# How to add/remove product to specific user's cart session in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm creating an API that adds/removes items from a user's cart session.

This is my Current Callback function but it's not working

```
function add_product_to_cart() {
    global $wpdb;

    $user_id         = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
    $wc_session_data = get_wc_session_data($user_id);

    // Get the persistent cart may be _woocommerce_persistent_cart can be in your case check in user_meta table
    $full_user_meta = get_wc_cart_user_meta($user_id);

    // create new Cart Object
    $cartObj = new WC_Cart();

    // Add old cart data to newly created cart object
    if($full_user_meta['cart']) {
        foreach($full_user_meta['cart'] as $sinle_user_meta) {
            $cartObj->add_to_cart( $sinle_user_meta['product_id'], $sinle_user_meta['quantity'], $sinle_user_meta['variation_id'] );
        }
    }

    // Add product and quantities coming in request to the new cart object
    $cartObj->add_to_cart( $_REQUEST['product_id'], $_REQUEST['quantity'], $_REQUEST['variation_id']);

    $updatedCart = [];
    foreach($cartObj->cart_contents as $key => $val) {
        unset($val['data']);
        $updatedCart[$key] = $val;
    }

    // If there is a current session cart, overwrite it with the new cart
    if($wc_session_data) {
        $wc_session_data['cart'] = serialize($updatedCart);
        $serializedObj = maybe_serialize($wc_session_data);
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_sessions', array('session_value' => $serializedObj), array('session_key' => $user_id));
    }

    // Overwrite the persistent cart with the new cart data
    $full_user_meta['cart'] = $updatedCart;
    update_user_meta($user_id, '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1', maybe_serialize($full_user_meta));
    wp_send_json(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Added product to cart successfully.'));
}
```

I need solution that update cart data at both (_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1 and woocommerce_sessions table)

Comment: What exactly is not working here? Why you can't update WC session by : 

`WC()->session->set( 'name_for_your_data' , $data );`

Comment: @JanRanostaj It's updating the data but totals are not being calculated. Could you please share the most genuine way to do this?